# How to show some notice when input is not correct and hide when input is correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want is something like this:
https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp

When you press sign up, you can see some red note.

his code is here:
https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/index.html#L95-L106
I tried to write it myself but failed all the time and don't know the reason. I am new in this field could you help me to write it? Thanks!
this is my simple code to test this part:
https://plnkr.co/edit/OL1QuesgZpqeEKoYS5cF?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
  <form name=signUpForm>
    <label for="name">
            <span>name:</span>
            <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" class="form-control" placeholder="your name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus ng-model="nameModel">
                <div class="input-error" ng-message="signUpForm.nameInput.$error" role="alert" ng-if="signUpForm.nameInput.$touched">
                    <div ng-message="required">
                        <p>Input your name please!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </label>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place ng-app, ng-controller in your template. Without ng-app, angular will not bootstrap ur template. ng-model, ng-if will work only after angular bootstrap the application

Comment: But after I add ng-app, it doesn't work as well, the note can't disappear after I input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <form name=signUpForm novalidate ng-submit="signUp()">
    <label for="nameInput">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" class="form-control" placeholder="your name" ng-required="true" autocomplete="name" autofocus ng-model="nameModel">
    <div ng-show="signUpForm.$submitted || signUpForm.nameInput.$touched">
      <p style="color:red" ng-show="signUpForm.nameInput.$error.required">This field is required</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

You need to initialize app with `ng-app`.
Hope this example will help you.

Comment: Can you use the ng-message? I think my code is not only the problem of ng-app. The origin code used ng-if and ng-message, and it works

Comment: hey guy, I found the first `ng-message` should be `ng-messages`, lol

Comment: I am glad you find a solution.